# Powerpoint 2016 on iMac

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, imac, microsoft-office-2016

I am a new iMac user.  I use Powerpoint all the time to create documents and save the documents in PDF format.  I was able to save my powerpoint documents as PDF files two days ago.  Today, I sit down to work and it is no longer an option.  I am only able to save powerpoint files as different types of powerpoint, not pdf, not jpeg nothing.  I don't know what I have done to make this happen and can find no support online.

Comment: You are 100% sure you performed this task on the OS X version of Office?    Verify printing to a PDF is a feature of Office 2016 on OS X

Comment: Can you "print" it as a pdf?  I know it is probably not the answer, but a temp workaround.  Have you tried to reinstall / repair Office?  Not sure if there is a repair option like on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerPoint 2016 Mac, to export to PDF, use `File > Export` and select PDF from the pop-up menu of supported export file formats.

(`File > Save` and `File > Save As…` only let you select PowerPoint-native formats.)

Be aware that in **ANY** Mac GUI app that allows printing, you can always print to PDF. This is a feature of the OS X printing subsystem, and no app that uses the normal OS X printing APIs can turn this off. However, if an app has built-in "Export to PDF" functionality, it's most likely so it can do a better, smarter export job rather than a relatively dumb print job. So always try native "Export to PDF" features before resorting to printing to PDF.